# My friend's digit code

Tags: cipher

My friend left me a code and went abroad. I can't communicate with him since he left. I tried some encryption methods to solve it but couldn't find anything significant. Here is the code.

> 001123581221
>
> 11235913
>
> 2134711182847
>
> 314591423375997

It should be in Turkish. We are using latin alphabet. I also added a photo of it, so it should be clear. I know that a full photo would be better but my friend just took that part. I hope I used the right keyword.

[image]

**Edit:** Found full photo. There is some kind of poem next to code. Rest of text looks useless. I will try to translate poem but really hard for me.

[image]

**Edit2:**  I tried to translate poem. Translated word by word because it is not meaningful even in Turkish.

> Lifetime-lie-their receivers
>
> Life-must-without battery-their charges
>
> Why-did you plant-death-this-(forbidden)-hand-calluses
>
> Come into leaf-again-grape-hounds

`yaşamalı` means `must live` and `yaşam` means `life` but he wrote with space so `yaşam alı` is wrong word in Turkish.

> Lifetime is lie receivers
>
> Must live batteryless charges
>
> Why did you planted calluses in this (forbidden) hand //Saying to death
>
> If grape hounds come into leaf

I hope it helps. That is all I can do. Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your second badge. Happy puzzling!

Comment: Yes, these are sequences where an element is the sum of the two previous elements, Fibonacci style. The second but last number is off by one in each sequence. I don't see how this is a cipher.

Comment: Can you translate the other text to English and post it, assuming it doesn't contain personal/sensitive information? I'm just wondering if perhaps the text and the code are something to be used together.

Comment: @jstnthms Actually it is personal. But I want to translate last line. It says "mystery of world in this..." and continious.

Comment: It may be good enough to transcribe the written poem to text: The numbers that Oray found may be indices to letters or words in that text for a kind of steganography. The circled text below the poem looks important. Could you please translate that?

Comment: The circled text below the poem says "P.S. Legendary brain storm". I don't think it is important.  Code and poem must be relative. They have same number of lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

The first numbers are not in the sequence, so $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$ are the order for the sequences. As a result;

> 0. $0\ 1\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 5\ 8\ 12\ 21$ is the first sequence, and the logic is easy, adding $n_{x-1}+n_{x-2}=n_x$. But $12$ is out of the order. It was supposed to be $13$.

Likely, the second sequence is supposed to be;

> 1. $1\ 2\ 3\ 5\ 9\ 13$ is the 2nd sequence, same thing, adding $n_{x-1}+n_{x-2}=n_x$. But $9$ is out of the order. It was supposed to be $8$.

The rest;

> 2. $1\ 3\ 4\ 7\ 11\ 18\ 28\ 47$ is the 3th sequence, same thing, adding $n_{x-1}+n_{x-2}=n_x$. But $28$ is out of the order. It was supposed to be $29$.

and

> 3. $1\ 4\ 5\ 9\ 14\ 23\ 37\ 59 \ 97$ is the 4th sequence, same thing, adding $n_{x-1}+n_{x-2}=n_x$. But $59$ is out of the order. It was supposed to be $60$.

As a result, the numbers are wrong in the sequence has to be the key to solve it but I could not find the rest yet:

> $12, 9, 28, 59$ and they are only one more or less than actual sequence.

Comment: The 21 is okay in the first sequence, but the 12 should be a 13.

Comment: @MOehm it the sequence was right, it would be $13$. since $8+5 = 13$.

Comment: That's what I said: The sequence goes 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 and the 12 is wrong, not the 21. All sequences have their second but last element off by one.

Comment: @Oray: Other than the first 0 (which is visibly spaced from the rest), the first numbers in each row can be considered in sequence too, 0+1=1, 1+1=2, 2+1=3, 3+1=4.

Answer (score -1):

The first two are

> the Fibonacci numbers.

The third is

> the Lucas numbers (2,1,3,4,7,11...)

The last one is

> the digits of pi (3.1415926535...)

Comment: I don't think they are...

Comment: With some changes, obviously.